# Do sideways springs fling differently based on my position?

Tags: celeste

When you collide with a sideways spring in Celeste, do they always fling you along the same path, or does your position matter when you hit the spring?

For example, on the Chapter 7 C-Side there's a section where you get launched by a sideways spring and need to boost up twice to clear a pillar of spikes. Sometimes I fail to get enough height to clear the spikes. Would I be getting more height if I hit the top-part of the sideways spring, or would I get the same amount of height if I hit the bottom of the spring?

[image: spike pillar in chapter 7 C-Side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing myself, I can confirm that hitting the top of the spring will get you more height.

To be more specific, where you collide with the spring does *not* affect the arc the spring launches you with. However, it does change the position you get launched from since the game does not "center" you when you hit a spring. In other words, a spring will always launch you the same way, but you will have more height to clear the upcoming spikes if you hit the top of the spring since you got launched from a higher starting position.